# Convergence of conditioned stochastic integral

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion, $f: [0, T] \to \mathbb R$ a bounded Borel measurable function, and $X_t$ a process independent of $B_t$ with sample paths that almost surely start at $0$, and are continuous and of bounded variation.

For every $\varepsilon > 0$, denote by $\Gamma_{\varepsilon}$ the event

$$\sup_{t \in [0,T]} |B_t - X_t| \leq \varepsilon.$$

Denote by $Y_t$ and $Z_t$ the processes $\int_{0}^t f(t) \ dB_t$ and $\int_{0}^t f(t) \ dX_t$ respectively, where the latter is a path-by-path ordinary Lebesgue-Stiltjes integral.

We write also $Y$ and $Z$ for the processes above, considered as $C([0, T])$-valued random variables.

> **Question:** Is it true that the conditioned random variables $Y|\Gamma_{\varepsilon}$ converge to $Z$ in law as $\varepsilon \to 0$?

*Note: Here we equip $C([0, T])$ with the topology of uniform convergence.*

**Remarks:**

1. The conditions on $X_t$ ensure that the event $\Gamma_{\varepsilon}$ has nonzero probability for every $\varepsilon > 0$, so that conditioning on it is well defined.
2. I believe that this is true, and the strategy should be to approximate the integral with respect to $B_t$ with elementary processes, and use this same approximation to write the Lebesgue-Stiltjes integral, and then bound the difference between the increments on $\Gamma_{\varepsilon}$. However the technicalities to do with convergence in law on $C[0, T]$ elude me.